# What is the use of $4f$ lens system for imaging?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics, lenses

Almost all the imaging experiments use $4f$ lens combination for imaging. What I don't understand is what is there a need for this combination. From my understanding, we can just use a convex lens. Place it at $f$ distance from the object and we will get the inverted image at $f$. How is a $4f$ lens combination useful here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4 lens system has distinct advantages over a simple convex lens setup.

Some advantages are:

1. Control Over Magnification and Image Placement: In a simple convex lens system, the magnification and placement of the image depend on the object's distance from the lens. If the object is at a distance of  (the focal length), the image is also formed at a distance  from the lens, but this setup limits flexibility. In a 4 system, you have two lenses, each at a distance of 2 from a central point. This arrangement allows for more control over where the image is formed and its magnification, regardless of small changes in the object's position.
2. Image Quality and Aberration Correction: A single lens can introduce aberrations like spherical aberration, chromatic aberration, and astigmatism. By using a 4 system, with carefully chosen lenses, these aberrations can be reduced, leading to a higher quality image.
3. Fourier Transform Properties: In optics, a 4 system can perform a Fourier transform operation on the light passing through it. The first lens takes the Fourier transform of the object, and the second lens reconstructs the image. This property can be used to perform various sorts of filtering.
4. Increased Working Distance: A 4 system offers a longer working distance compared to a single lens system. This can be advantageous in practical situations where space is needed between the lens and the object or the image.